# illegal reflective access error when im running server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/xxxx/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/xxxxexexe/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
```

When running my server from my Spring application, I get these errors, but I have no idea why this is happening, and I have searched the web for more information but it is not clear to me.
I use Java 8 . Im also using Eclipse IDE

Comment: It is a warning **not** an error. You are using an old version of Spring and java8 and up issue warnings when it does reflective access (which is restricted/forbidden in Java 11 and up).

Comment: and what about org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException ?

Comment: That is unrelated to the warnings.